# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring] through eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, gwt

I've read over all of the other SO posts about this problem, but none of them deal with camel, and the applicationContext.xml. I'm at my wits end as I've been trying to figure this out for more than a week now.

Problem: I can run my GWT application through Tomcat 6 just fine. But as soon as I try to execute it through Eclipse using Run As Web Application, I receive this output to the console:

```
[WARN] Server class 'org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/company/m2/repo/org/springframework/spring-web/2.5.6/spring-web-2.5.6.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
[WARN] Server resource 'log4j.properties' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/company/projects/svn/reco/services/portal/trunk/portal-trunk/portal-um/src/test/resources/' to the web app classpath for this session
[WARN] Server class 'com.company.session.PortalSessionListener' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/company/m2/repo/serviceUtil/serviceUtil/trunk/serviceUtil-trunk.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
[WARN] Server class 'org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/company/m2/repo/org/springframework/spring-context/2.5.6/spring-context-2.5.6.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
[WARN] Server class 'org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/company/m2/repo/org/springframework/spring-beans/2.5.6/spring-beans-2.5.6.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
[WARN] Server class 'org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/company/m2/repo/org/springframework/spring-core/2.5.6/spring-core-2.5.6.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
[WARN] Server class 'org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/company/m2/repo/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.4.0/gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Failed startup of context com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@192232de{/,C:\company\projects\svn\reco\services\portal\trunk\portal-trunk\portal-entrypoint\target\portal-entrypoint-trunk}
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

  at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1294)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
  at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
  at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

I have no clue what to make of this and neither do any of my coworkers. I also don't know what other information to include in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to update with my solution. Turns out that in my project properties under `Google > Web Application` the `War Directory:` wasn't pointing correctly at my WAR directory. I changed it to point at `target/ROOT` and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your eclipse "run as web application" setting is using Jetty instead of tomcat, and somehow that result in different classpath configuration. By the look of it you're likely to miss some jars (camel related) on jetty.

This normally happen if you don't use dependency management like maven, ie: you have to consciously manage what path is / not included in your classpath at which environment.

An easier approach is to use the same container for both production and development, and ensure additional jar you need is included in WEB-INF/lib by declaring it in maven pom.

Comment: I am using Maven. I don't really know what you mean by "use the same container for both production and development" And everything I need should be declared in the pom, other devs on my team have this working just fine so it has to be something with my setup, not the pom.

Comment: By the way I think http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring doesn't came from spring-camel jar, but the actual camel jar. Did you double check you really have this on classpath?

Answer (score 0):

When running a GWT application from Eclipse in dev mode it uses the classpath as defined in your debug configuration. This is the build path of code you are using to compile plus any other jars or folders you have manually added. In addition, because it is a web app it will also use any jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

When you get the message

> [WARN] Server class
>   'org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener' could not be
>   found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath    [WARN]
>   Adding classpath entry
>   'file:/C:/company/m2/repo/org/springframework/spring-web/2.5.6/spring-web-2.5.6.jar'
>   to the web app classpath for this session

then this means the code could not be found in the WEB-INF/lib folder but was found on the classpath as defined by your debug configuration. GWT dev mode will add this jar to your running web app classpath.

Generally this all works fine but if your code relies on classes that are looked up dynamically using some sort of classpath searching mechanism this process does not work. This is what is happening here - the namespace handler and associated schema will be in the camel jar but this is not on your classpath.

The answer is simple - just add the jar containing the namespace handler to the WEB-INF/lib folder.

I have this issue a lot - mainly with Spring but also the RSS library Rome. My project is built using Maven and to manage this I have configured Maven with a devmode profile that includes all the runtime dependencies I need with a goal that copies all my dependencies into the WEB-INF/lib folder. This means I can manage all my dependencies from Maven - useful when sharing a project.

Comment: The camel-spring-2.0-M3.jar **is** in the WEB-INF/lib folder :(

Comment: Also, I seem to have several WEB-INF folders. There's one located at `portal-entrypoint/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`, but there is no lib folder in that one. Then there is one at `portal-entrypoint/target/ROOT/WEB-INF` and that folder contains a deploy and lib folder along with a ton of jars. And finally there is one at `portal-entrypoint/target/portal-entrypoint-trunk/WEB-INF`, but there are only classes and deploy folders. No lib folder. And all of those locations contain an `applicationContext.xml` and a `web.xml` file.

Comment: The GWT Eclipse plugin uses the war directory as configured in `Project Properties > Google > Web Application`. You should find it uses the WEB-INF/lib folder under there in dev mode. That's where you'll need to put the jars that include the namespace handler and schema. It can get a little complicated with Maven, see http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/war-folder.html.

Comment: This may be useful if you haven't seen it already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442391/gwt-web-app-vs-system-classpath-for-dynamic-loaded-classes